# joomla exception handling with DB error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Trying to do exception handling and logging. So if I have something like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('*')
$query->from('#__users');

try
{
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();
}
catch (RuntimeException $e)
{
    $e->getMessage();
    JLog::add('This query failed: '.$query);

}
```

My question is how best to test my exception code? Taking down the DB will just get Joomla to output this error and I never get into my exception code:

`Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.`

I want to be able to verify the exception and log get printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a throw statement in the try part of your try/catch section.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it. First initialise loggers in entry point file:

```
JLog::addLogger(
    array('text_file' => 'com_mycom.php'),
    JLog::ALL ^ JLog::ERROR,
    'com_mycom'
);

JLog::addLogger(
    array('text_file' => 'com_mycom.errors.php'),
    JLog::ERROR,
    'com_mycom'
);
```

Then use it in models:

```
try
{
    $rows = $this->_db->loadObjectList();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    JLog::add($e->getMessage(), JLog::ERROR, 'com_mycom');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is useful but not what I was looking for. I just want to know how to trigger the catch statement with my system so I can test it actually works.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand you correctly. The best approach to test is to make incorrect query, like selecting not existing field for example.